# Can not get @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity working

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to configure `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` on a java based configuration, but the methods being annotated are being ignored by the aspect. I've covered all the problems usually encountered with the same XML config, my annotation is on a security configuration part of the root context, and my service classes are also managed under the root context.

In the following `TestService` is an interface containing my `@PreAuthorize` annotation which I also have a corresponding implementation that I have also tried annotating directly.

**AppInitializer.java**

```
public class AppInitializer
        extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
            RootConfig.class,
            SecurityConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

**RootConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.acme.app.service"})
public class RootConfig {
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("pass").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
            extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
        @Override
        protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return userDetailsService;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBeanCreation() {
        Collection<UserDetails> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(getUser("user", "password", "USER"));
        users.add(getUser("admin", "pass", "ADMIN", "USER"));
        UserDetailsService uds = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
        return uds;
    }

    private UserDetails getUser(String user, String pass, String... roles) {
        // impl omitted...
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter
            extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().realmName("com.acme.app")
                .and().sessionManagement();
        }
        @Override
        protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return userDetailsService;
        }
    }
}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.acme.app.config",
                               "com.acme.app.controllers"},
               excludeFilters = {
                   @Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                           value = {
                               WebConfig.class,
                               SecurityConfig.class
                           })
               })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver getLocaleResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver bean = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        bean.setCookieName("clientlanguage");
        bean.setCookieMaxAge(100000);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(lci);
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
        CustomTilesInitializer ti = new CustomTilesInitializer();
        TilesConfigurer res = new TilesConfigurer();
        res.setCompleteAutoload(true);
        res.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml");
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.tiles();
        registry.enableContentNegotiation(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/home", "/");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/aboutme").setViewName("aboutme");
    }

}
```

**TestService.java**

```
public interface TestService {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_DUMMY_ROLE')")
    BasicData getDataSecured();
}
```

Note that I also have spring-aop in my pom.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The annotation must be on the implementing class not the interface and make sure that your `WebConfig` isn't scanning for the same component also.

Comment: @M.Deinum I put them on both, but [the reference documentation example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-method) has them on the interface. Will include my `WebConfig`

Comment: Your RootConfig is included when scanning. I would (in this case) exclude all `@Configuration` classes from being detected automatically. Due to the detection your component scan is again instantiating beans those beans aren't covered by the security aspect as they live in different contexts.

Comment: Good find, please add as an answer so I can accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `RootConfig` is included when scanning is done for the `DispatcherServlet`.

I would (in this case) exclude all `@Configuration` classes from being detected automatically. Due to the detection your component scan is again instantiating beans those beans aren't covered by the security aspect as they live in different contexts.